# Test scenario for Android porting test

Tags: android, testcase

I am new to testing of Android porting. Could you kindly share with me a testing scenario, any reference document or ref. template for such test case?

Comment: Hi urvish - Out of curiosity what sort of porting are you doing?  Is it porting the OS to another device?  Is it porting an app from a different platform to Android?  The more specific you can be the better answers that the community can provide.

Answer (score 1):

You can get ideas from
[Android unified testing initiative](http://unifiedtestinginitiative.org/blog/)
It has a comprehensive list of tests for Android applications.  And here are some types of Android application tests from [the AQuA website](http://www.appqualityalliance.org/files/AQuA_testing_criteria_for_Android_v1.3_oct_2_2012.pdf):

1.1 OTA Install

1.2 Long launch time

3.1 Send/Receive Data

3.4 Resource downloading

5.2  Message  – Receive

5.3 Incoming call

6.1  Memory card operation

7.1 Readability

7.3 Screen Repainting

7.5 Key Layout ease of use

7.8 Function progress

7.10 Multiple display format handling

7.11 Different screen sizes

7.12 Multiple format input handling

7.14 Spelling errors

7.15 Technical text errors

8.1 Language – correct operation

8.3 Language – supported formats

9.1 Suspend/resume from main menu

9.2 Suspend/resume while executing

10.1 Application Mute option

11.1 Help and About

12.1 Functionality Sanity Check

13.1 Scrolling in menus

13.3 Pause

15.1 Application Stability

15.2 Application behaviour after forced close

16.2  Data Deletion

Comment: Please just don't post links.

Answer (score -1):

Might you can get your stuff from https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/android-porting

Comment: Please just don't post links.